# How to call Android layout in Unity?

Tags: android, android-layout, unity-game-engine

I am finding the solution of my problem but not satisfied from all of them.
I create an android library which shows a ad view layout witch is and know I want to call this layout in unity but can't find any solution please anyone help me how can I call my layout in unity?

```
public class RedeemLayout extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener,HttpCallBacks {
    public Dialog      dialogBox;
    public ImageButton close;
    public ImageView   advert;
    public TextView    location_text;
    TextView    tv_massagetext;
    EditText    et_redeemdetial;
    Button      btn_redem;
    ImageButton btn_closead;
    DeviceInfo device = new DeviceInfo();
    String           adClickUrl;
    HttpNetworkCalls httpNetworkCalls;
    Context          context;
    Activity         activity;
    ImageView        bmImage;
    FrameLayout      redeemLayout;
    AdInfo ad;
    private AdInfo   adInfo;
    private UserInfo user;

    public RedeemLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public RedeemLayout(Activity activity, Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public RedeemLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {

        super(context, attr);
        initialize(context);
        this.context = context;

    }

    private void initialize(Context context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.ad_lyout, this);
        tv_massagetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.massagetext);
        et_redeemdetial = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.redeemdetail);
        btn_redem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_redeem);
        btn_closead = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_CloseFullScreenAd);
        bmImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.adimage);
        redeemLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.redeemLayout);


        httpNetworkCalls = new HttpNetworkCalls(this);
        btn_redem.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_closead.setOnClickListener(this);


        DownloadAdAccordingToLocation();

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        int i = view.getId();
        if (i == R.id.btn_redeem) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Thanks for Redeem You will get Massage soon...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("ad_id",ad.getAdId());
            data.put("app_id","1");
            data.put("location","lahore");
            data.put("session","1");

            try {
                httpNetworkCalls.post(data, API.UPDATE_IMPRESSIONS);
                // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
        }
        if (i == R.id.btn_CloseFullScreenAd) {
            redeemLayout.removeAllViews();
            redeemLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("ad_id",ad.getAdId());
            data.put("app_id","1");
            data.put("location","lahore");
            data.put("session","1");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Thanks for Redeem You will get Massage soon...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                httpNetworkCalls.post(data, API.UPDATE_IMPRESSIONS);
                // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    }

    private void DownloadAdAccordingToLocation() {

        try {
            httpNetworkCalls.get(API.RANDOM_ADVERTISEMENT);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void adButtonClicked(View v) {
        // FullScreenAdDialog db = new FullScreenAdDialog(this, ad, updateAdClick);
        // db.show();
//        Intent x = new Intent(xcontext, AdActivity.class);
//        x.putExtra("image_link", ad.getImage_link());
//        x.putExtra("url", ad.getUrl());
//        x.putExtra("adid", ad.getAdId());
//        x.putExtra("adclickurl", updateAdClick);
//        startActivity(x);

    }

    @Override
    public void HttpResponse(final int apiCode, final JSONObject response, final boolean isSuccess) {

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (apiCode == API.RANDOM_ADVERTISEMENT) {
                        if (response.has("networkError")) {
                            Log.e("Error", response.getString("networkError"));
                        } else {
                            ad = AdInfo.fromJson(response);
                            if (ad.isSuccess()) {

                                Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
                                builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                                        redeemLayout.removeAllViews();
                                        redeemLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }

                                });
                                Picasso pic = builder.build();
                                pic.load(ad.getImage_url()).into(bmImage);

//                        Picasso.with(context)
//                                .load(ad.getImage_url())
//                                .error(R.drawable.imagecross)
//                                .into(bmImage);
                            } else {
                                Log.e("Error", response.getString("parseError"));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

and call my library in android app like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.test);
        RedeemLayout redeemLayout= new RedeemLayout(this, this);
        redeemLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(redeemLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please precise your question. This is too broad. Add code what you've already tried. If you're insecure, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i added the code as well of my ad library layout i can't find the desire tutorial for call it in unity :(

Answer (score 1):

It's more unity3d question. You cannot call your layout directly, you can only send message to android code. Read Unity3d script documentation (or google for code) of AndroidJavaClass and AndroidJavaObject.

From Android perspective I think that you should implement some kind of static method that you can call from unity and it should broadcast or send event in event bus that will be handled by your advertisement engine.

Unity part of code should be similar to this:

```
AndroidJavaClass javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.mypackage.MyClassWithMyStaticMethod");
javaClass.getStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("MyStaticMethod", 42);
```

Android MyClassWithMyStaticMethod class should implement:

```
public static void MyStaticMethid(int param) {...}
```

Check this doc: [AndroidJavaClass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html)

Comment: @ArslanYasin Nice, but what you want to call on your view?

PS. Adding network calls etc. inside layout is not best idea.

Comment: i want to call this layout in unity this is my ad network and i want to build a plugin for unity,

Comment: @ArslanYasin Because Android has different lifecycle than unity you cannot call layout directly, you've to broadcast message and hope that layout will receive it.

Comment: can you give me any tutorial of broadcast massage?

Comment: [vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

TL;DR; method that is called from unity should send broadcast and when needed class that manages layouts should receive messages.

Comment: @ArslanYasin [sample project](https://github.com/bholota/Unity2AndroidMessage/tree/master) just instead showin Toast message, do work on your particular layout.